# How to animate multiple numbers in html?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im trying to animate numbers in html. But somehow I can´t animate multiple numbers at once. How can I animate multiple numbers? The problem is where the second number should be Is blank... But I don´t understand why the second animation is blank :c

Here´s a screenshot of what it looks like right now. The first animation works but the second one doesn´t. "?" is where the second animation should be.

[image: Screenshot of the finished result without the second animation]

HTML:

```
 <section id="gamemodes">
    <h1>ABOUT US</h1>
    <p>Here you can view more about us.</p>

    <div class="row fixed-width">
        <div class="col-md mode">


            <h2>ABOUT X10 GAMING</h2>
            <p><strong><div id="value"> </div> Members</p></strong><br>

            <p><strong><div id="events"> </div> Events</p></strong>
        </div>

        

        <div class="col-md img">
            <img class="res-img" src="img/ueberuns.png">
        </div>

    </div>
 

</section>
```

CSS:

```
#value {
    display: inline;
}

#events {
    display: inline;
}
```

JS:

```
<script>
        function animateValue(obj, start, end, duration) {
            let startTimestamp = null;
            const step = (timestamp) => {
                if (!startTimestamp) startTimestamp = timestamp;
                const progress = Math.min((timestamp - startTimestamp) / duration, 1);
                obj.innerHTML = Math.floor(progress * (end - start) + start);
                if (progress < 1) {
                    window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
                }
            };
            window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
        }

        const obj = document.getElementById("value"); 
        animateValue(obj, 0, 5, 500);

        
    </script>

<script>
    function animateValue(obj, start, end, duration) {
        let startTimestamp = null;
        const step = (timestamp) => {
            if (!startTimestamp) startTimestamp = timestamp;
            const progress = Math.min((timestamp - startTimestamp) / duration, 1);
            obj.innerHTML = Math.floor(progress * (end - start) + start);
            if (progress < 1) {
                window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
            }
        };
        window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
    }

    const obj = document.getElementById("events"); 
    animateValue(obj, 0, 5, 500);

    
</script>
```

Comment: You are defining two functions with the same name `animateValue` in global scope. One will shadow the other.

Comment: Yes I agree with @RuudHelderman, but that may just bee that you copied it in twice on accident on your post..

Comment: So what do I have to do exactly?

Comment: @ancxFlat Since the two function definitions are identical, just remove one of them. A bigger problem is probably the redefinition of global variable `obj`; that was giving me a syntax error in Chrome. Keep an eye on your JavaScript console when testing! Rename one of the variables, or better, avoid using global variables altogether.